# Specflow - TearDown failed for test fixture Account.AddBankAccountFeature BoDi.ObjectContainerException

Tags: c#, specflow

I am creating a new Selenium framework using C#. Build is ok but tests failed due to the following error.

> TearDown failed for test fixture Account.AddBankAccountFeature
> BoDi.ObjectContainerException : Interface cannot be resolved:
> TechTalk.SpecFlow.UnitTestProvider.IUnitTestRuntimeProvider('nunit')
> TearDown : System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to
> an instance of an object.

Here is my cs file

```
using System;
using TechTalk.SpecFlow;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace Account
{
    [Binding]
   
    public class AddBankAccountSteps
    {
        IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        [Given(@"User is at the Login Page")]
        public void GivenUserIsAtTheLoginPage()
        {
            driver.Url = "https://go.xxx.com/";
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(driver.Url);
        }
        
        
        [When(@"User enter UserName and Password")]
        public void WhenUserEnterUserNameAndPassword()
        {
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("email")).SendKeys("aa@ss.com");
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("password")).SendKeys("aaa");
        }
        
        [When(@"User click on the LogIn button")]
        public void WhenUserClickOnTheLogInButton()
        {
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("submitButton")).Click();
        }
        
        [Then(@"User can login in ")]
        public void ThenUserCanLoginIn()
        {
            var expectedURL = "https://go.xxx.com/Dashboard/default.aspx";
            var actualURL = driver.Url;
            Assert.AreEqual(expectedURL, actualURL);

        }

    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Here is something wrong with your installed NuGet packages. Which one have you added to your project? And in which version?

Comment: Can you please add the stack trace? Do you have any before or after scenario hooks?